# Is the function $f(n)=$ "First prime greater than or equal to $n$" from the natural numbers to the prime numbers bijective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{P}$

as **f(n)=First prime greater than or equal to it.**

$\mathbb{P}$: Set of prime numbers

Is this function bijective?

Comment: What is $f(4)$?  What is $f(5)$?

Comment: $f(n) = inf \{ \mathbb{P} \cap [n, \infty) \}$

Comment: As many as $$7$$ users saw fit to upvote this? My, my...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As already pointed out, $f(n) $ is **not** a bijective function because it is not an injective function. For example, $f(6) = f(7) = 7$.

Maybe consider

$$f(n) = n^\text{th}\ \text{prime number} $$

That is a bijection.

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, as hinted in the comment, the function $f$ is not bijective. This is because several natural numbers correspond to the same prime under the function, thus clearly violating injectivity.